# Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics' (cannot run iOS flutter app after add Firebase Analytics)

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

```
Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:86:5


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:88:5


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:96:3


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:104:3


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:112:3


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:117:3


Generics Issue (Xcode): No type or protocol named 'FIRConsentType'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:124:22


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRConsentTypeAdStorage'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:128:15


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRConsentStatusGranted'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:129:39


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRConsentStatusDenied'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:129:65


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRConsentTypeAnalyticsStorage'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:132:15


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRConsentStatusGranted'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:133:46


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRConsentStatusDenied'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:133:72


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:136:3


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:142:3


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'
/Users/macbook/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.4.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:147:29
```

in VS code when I run with FLutter run or run with debug, it always throw error as above. But when I run the app with xcode it works but (i cannot make use of hot reload with xcode so i should fix this issue =(( ).

I try to change many version of firebase but they all does not solve

here my version of dependencies in yaml

environment:
sdk: '>=3.0.2 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
firebase_core: ^2.15.0
firebase_analytics: ^10.4.0

Comment: Did you solve that issue?